# Turn string into simple JSON in scala

Tags: json, string, scala

I have a string in scala which in terms of formatting, it is a json, for example

```
{"name":"John", "surname":"Doe"}
```

But when I generate this value it is initally a string. I need to convert this string into a json but I cannot change the output of the source. So how can I do this conversion in Scala? (I cannot use the Play Json library.)

Comment: I'm very confused about your question. You have a JSON string, but it isn't being accepted by your client API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have strings as

```
{"name":"John", "surname":"Doe"}
```

and if you want to save to `elastic` as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-write-json) then you should use `parseRaw` instead of `parseFull`.

`parseRaw` will return you `JSONType` and `parseFull` will return you `map`

You can do as following

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._

val jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Doe\"}"
val parsed = JSON.parseRaw(jsonString).get.toString()
```

And then use the `jsonToEs` api as

```
sc.makeRDD(Seq(parsed)).saveJsonToEs("spark/json-trips")
```

**Edited**
As @Aivean pointed out, when you already have json string from source, you won't be needing to convert to json, you can just do

```
if jsonString is {"name":"John", "surname":"Doe"}
sc.makeRDD(Seq(jsonString)).saveJsonToEs("spark/json-trips")
```

Comment: What's the point of parsing Json and then rendering it back to string? It seems that OP should just create an RDD from his original string and call `saveJsonToEs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scala.util.parsing.json` to convert JSON in string format to JSON (which is basically `HashMap` datastructure),

eg.

```
scala> import scala.util.parsing.json._
import scala.util.parsing.json._

scala> val json = JSON.parseFull("""{"name":"John", "surname":"Doe"}""")
json: Option[Any] = Some(Map(name -> John, surname -> Doe))
```

To navigate the json format,

```
scala> json match { case Some(jsonMap : Map[String, Any]) => println(jsonMap("name")) case _ => println("json is empty") }
John
```

nested json example,

```
scala> val userJsonString = """{"name":"John", "address": { "perm" : "abc", "temp" : "zyx" }}"""
userJsonString: String = {"name":"John", "address": { "perm" : "abc", "temp" : "zyx" }}

scala> val json = JSON.parseFull(userJsonString)
json: Option[Any] = Some(Map(name -> John, address -> Map(perm -> abc, temp -> zyx)))

scala> json.map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("address")).map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]("perm"))
res7: Option[String] = Some(abc)
```

Comment: I have my strings inside a variable ex. `val entry = <String>`. How do I parse my variable entry inside parsefull like that?

Comment: what do you mean you have strings inside variable ex. are you saying your string is stored in a variable not hardcoded as in example?

Comment: Sorry, with ex I meant example. But yeah, the strings are not hardcoded, I get them from a source, they are stored inside some variable, and I have to turn this variable into a json. Sorry for not being too clear.

Comment: then simply do `JSON.parseFull(your_variable)`, or am I missing something?? see my second example where I'm using variable too.

Comment: It does run ok, but the output type is Option[Any], which is not accepted by my other methods. I need a proper json type :(

Comment: I want to get the data from a database (but it comes out as string) and then store it as Json inside of elastic. It wants a json value, Option[Any] is not acceptable. Maybe it should accept a Map instead?
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-write-json